# Class App\Http\Controllers\ does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

This is my Route:

```
 Route::get('/hello', '@HomeController@index');
```

This is my HomeController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use app\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Requests;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Models\Activity;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller {

   public function index() {
    $lastActivity = Spatie\Activitylog\Models\Activity::all();
    return view('activity'), compact('lastActivity'));
   }

}
```

But I keep on getting an error message:

```
 ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
 Class App\Http\Controllers\ does not exist
```

What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: What is your Laravel version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the first of controller you do not need to put `@`, its just for method of controller.

```
 Route::get('/hello', 'HomeController@index');
```

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra @ in your method call.

```
'@HomeController@index'
```

should be

```
'HomeController@index'
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever errors of type *ReflectionException* occur, you should check the routes in the `routes/api.php` and `routes/web.php` files to correct them ok understand do it carefully next time.